# Return Random Result from JSON using PyMongo

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pymongo

I'm attempting to retrieve a random result from a collection of JSON data using PyMongo. I'm using Flask and MongoDB. Here is how it is set up:

```
def getData():
    dataCollection = db["data"]
    for item in dataCollection.find({},{"Category":1,"Name":1,"Location":1,"_id":0}):
        return (jsonify(item)
```

`return (jsonify(item)` returns 1 result and it is always the first one. How can I randomize this?

I tried importing the random module (`import random`) and switched the last line to `random.choice(jsonify(item)` but that results in an error.

Here is what the data looks like that was imported into MongoDB:

```
[
  {
    "Category":"Tennis",
    "Name":"ABC Courts",
    "Location":"123 Fake St"
  },
  {
    "Category":"Soccer",
    "Name":"XYZ Arena",
    "Location":"319 Ace Blvd"
  },
  {
    "Category":"Basketball",
    "Name":"Dome Courts",
    "Location":"8934 My Way"
  },
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're always getting one result because `return jsonify(item)` ends the request. jsonify returns a response it does not only just turn result from Mongo into a json object. if you want to turn your Mongo result into a sequence use `list` then `random.choice`

```
item = random.choice(list(dataCollection.find({},{"Category":1,"Name":1,"Location":1,"_id":0}))

return jsonify(item)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!